# "Why yes, yes you can" vs. "Yes, you can"

Tags: phrase-usage

I came across **[this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295610/the-meaning-of-the-word-flack)** today and the accepted answer starts with "Why yes, yes you can". Why didn't the person simply write 'yes, you can' instead of adding two extra words? Is this person trying to emphasize the obviousness of the usage of the word in the given question? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why** can serve as an interjection. From the Merriam-Webster Dictionary:

> **[Why](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/why)** -- used at the beginning of a statement, especially to express surprise
>   ***Why***, here's what I was looking for!

So you guessed right:

> Is this person trying to emphasize the obviousness of the usage of the word in the given question?

Why, yes, of course!

---

As Merriam-Webster notes, this usage of **why** is "somewhat old-fashioned".

An example of usage ([The Beggar's Opera](http://www.bartleby.com/202/2.html), 1728; *[audio record](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pBakEct5Lc)*, another *[audio record](https://youtu.be/Ywn9jxsJkzI?t=314)*):

> LUCY.
>   **Why** how now, Madam Flirt?
>             If you thus must chatter;
>           And are for flinging Dirt,
>             Let’s try who best can spatter;
>                       Madam Flirt!
>
> POLLY.
>   **Why** how now, saucy Jade;
>             Sure the Wench is tipsy!
>           How can you see me made
>             The Scoff of such a Gipsy?
>                       Saucy Jade!

Comment: +1. But it's been used by song writers a *little* more contemporary than John Gay: *Competition? Why yes, I would love some / How the fuck they getting mad 'cause they run done / Mad 'cause I’m getting money in abundance /
Man I can’t even count all of these hundreds* - Nicki Minaj, ['Check It Out](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/nickiminaj/checkitout.html), 2010

Comment: @StoneyB - I know, it's only that I chanced upon *Beggar's Opera* recently. (0:

Comment: Terrific piece. If you don't already know it you should check out the Brecht/Weill adaptation, too.

Comment: +1 Great to see people here exhibiting not just excellent language skills but a great wit too!

Comment: Why yes, I would love to have my anus probed.

Answer (score 0):

Another subtle difference in meaning between "Yes you can" and "Why yes, yes you can" is that "yes you can" is a straightforward statement of giving permission or judgment of ability of the listener to perform some action, while "Why yes, yes you can" is often used by a speaker who is trying to be humorous about a situation where it should be obvious to the listener that they shouldn't have needed to ask permission in the first place.

```
Q: Can I eat that food?
A: Yes you can.

Q: Can I fall down?
A: Why yes, yes you can.
```